# PyCharm не предлагает импортировать нужные методы, получается только вручную прописав импорт

Tags: pycharm, библиотеки, импорт

После клона моего пет-проекта с гитхаба на новую ОСь (переустанавливал убунту), плохо стали работать импорты [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам проект работает без проблем, без ошибок, но импорты приходится писать от руки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать File> invalidate caches and restart,но не помогло

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы работали импорты для сторонних библиотек требуется настроить интерпретатор в IDE. `File | Settings | Project: <NAME> | Python Interpreter`. И там нужно выбрать (или создать и выбрать) интерпретатор для проекта. В него надо будет еще и поставить зависимости.

Для того чтобы работали импорты относительно проекта, в случае если исходники лежат не в корне, то нужно настроить source root. Для этого надо выделить директорию где лежат исходники ПКМ по ней и `Mark Directory us -> Source root`

Comment: Спасибо большое, разметка помогла